# How to change corresponing author during review process

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission, authorship, editors, correspondence

I recently graduated my PhD and will take on a new opportunity next month. To follow up two papers that I have submitted a couple of months ago, which are still under review (during a very lengthly process, apparently), I would like to either

- add my supervisor as a second corresponding author, or
- change the correpsonding author to my supervisor (if only one is permitted).

Current papers are submitted to Nature Scientific Reports and Value in Health. There are, however, no actions possible in the system during an ongoing review. My supervisor does not have an account in the system (yet).

What should I do? Email the editorial office with an update of the review process and ask for this change? Will my supervisor be able to access the manuscript in the system if he needs to make a new account?

Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether any of it is possible and what the result will be can only be answered by the journal itself. So, ask them for advice on how to proceed.

This will vary by journal. You need to ask them.